# How should prove that a function is onto?

Tags: functions

### This is what is done to prove that a function is onto:

> For functions given by formulas we proceed along the following lines.
> Step 1: Let y be any element of the codomain and x an element of the domain. Step2:  We solve the equation y = f(x) for x. Step 3: This gives us a possible candidate for a domain element. We prove it is a suitable domain element by substituting this value into the function.

In the step of solving $y=f(x)$ for $x$ will clearly show us whether the function is onto or not by evaluating the solution. But I don't see the necessity of the next step of verifying that the solution will give back us $y$.

Is there an example where only the last step will be false?

I have searched the necessity of the last step, but I haven't got a satisfactory answer.

Please, help me.

Comment: You just need to show that some $x$ exists such that $f(x) = y$.

Comment: A function $f$ is surjective (onto) iff Range$(f)$=Codomain$(f)$. You simply need to show that $\forall y\in\textrm{Codomain}(f)\exists f(x)=y~,~x\in\textrm{Dom}(f)$

Comment: Is there an example only the last step fails?
For instance, is there an example such that by solving f(x)=y for x proves $x\in D_f$ but fails to prove $\forall y \in Codomain(f)\ \exists f(x)=y, x\in D_f$?